# Can we make a Script or Job Schedule for PostgreSQL database Back-UP?

Tags: postgresql, job-scheduling, pgadmin, pgagent

I am using PostgreSQL Database, I am running a Database Server .

My **PostgreSQL Version** is :

```
postgres=# select version();
                           version
-------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit
(1 row)
```

**My Requirement:**

Can we make a `Script or a Job-Schedule` to Run for Keeping the `Back-Up` of ***PostgreSQL*** Database for every 2 Days ?

Is there a way for doing that ?

Can we Run any Scripts or Job-Scheduling Jobs for making this happen?

Is there a way of doing that using **PgAgent**! I am using **PgAdminIII**.

Comment: how about a cronjob with pg_dump?

Comment: I am not aware of it! @foibs can u provide any refernces

Comment: I assume you have postgres on a windows machine, so that should do it  http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Windows

Comment: @foibs Can u provide the Script as an answer for making backup For Every 2 Days. It will be help full for the visitors, for this Question. Regards

Comment: Ok, I added an answer, mostly taken by the link above. Did you succeed with the automatic backup?

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Windows)

To achieve an automated backup in a windows environment:

**1. Create a .pgpass file**

(I called mine pgpass.conf) and put it somewhere secure. I have it in a subdirectory under 
the script that runs the backup.

pgpass contains host access information in this format

`hostname:port:database:username:password`

Lock down the .pgpass file
Using NTFS permissions, disable access to this file for everybody except the user pg is running as
(If you're running pg under the system account, then you should set it to use it's own user credentials)

**2. Create a script to call pg_dumpall**

For example:

```
SET PGPASSFILE=C:\foo\bar\PG_BACKUP\PGPASSFILE\pgpass.conf
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\pg_dumpall.exe" -U postgres_username  > C:\foo\bar\PG_BACKUP\db.out current
```

The firstline is the location of your pgpass file. The second line is the pg_dumpall command which outputs your whole database to the file `C:\foo\bar\PG_BACKUP\db.out`

**3. Create a scheduled task**

The command is

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "C:\foo\bar\PG_BACKUP\pg_backup.bat"`

and it starts in the directory

`C:\foo\bar\PG_BACKUP`

Here's a good tutorial on how to create scheduled tasks on windows:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-windows-programs-on-a-schedule/.

You can find plenty such tutorials and info with a simple search.